# Error registering bean with name

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

now I'm handling new module, its using Hibernate and spring, I'm new for this technolgies, since need to solve this ASAP, I'm looking for advice for this, when I deploy my application in server, I'm getting below error,

```
     SRVE0180I: [RbsAdapterWeb] [/IVRAdapterWeb] [Servlet.LOG]: Loading Spring root WebApplicationContext
[11/21/11 13:00:46:709 WST] 778b4480 XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
[11/21/11 13:00:46:763 WST] 778b4480 ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  Context initialization failed
[11/21/11 13:00:46:774 WST] 778b4480 ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  TRAS0014I: È stata registrata la seguente eccezione org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'hcm' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Class that bean class [it.elsag.echannel.utils.HCMAbstraction] depends on not found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/elsag/echannel/common/PasswordRulesException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/elsag/echannel/common/PasswordRulesException
```

of course its showing the class is not found but when I check the is exist by check the ear file,

can anyone help me to check this, I'm running on WebSphere

thanks in advance

Comment: where did you check that the class exists? On what server are you running your application (seems like WebSphere)?

Comment: pasting some code would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the path of the deployed EAR on the server. If you're working with Network Deployment, should be something like:
`{WAS_INSTALL_DIR}/profiles/{deployment_manager_dir}/config/cells/{cell_name}/applications/{app}.ear`

If it's a standalone WAS, it's something like:
`{WAS_INSTALL_DIR}/profiles/{your_profile_dir}/config/cells/{cell_name}/applications/{app}.ear`

If you see that the class isn't in **that** ear, then you found the problem.

In Network Deployment, such errors often happen because of an update to the ear, that added some classses, and that update wasn't yet synchronized with the nodes. Try synchronizing the server's node an restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your app couldn't find the class in the classpath.

To fix this, dump the classpath to make sure it contains what you expect. Use this code:

```
public static String determineClassPath( ClassLoader cLoader ) {

    List<URL> urls = getClassPath( cLoader );
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    String delim = "";

    for( URL url : urls ) {
        buffer.append( delim ).append( url );
        delim = "\n";
    }

    return buffer.toString().trim();
}

public static List<URL> getClassPath( ClassLoader cLoader ) {

    List<ClassLoader> loaders = new ArrayList<ClassLoader>();
    ClassLoader current = cLoader;
    while( current != null ) {
        loaders.add( 0, current );
        current = current.getParent();
    }

    List<URL> result = new ArrayList<URL>();
    for( ClassLoader loader : loaders ) {
        determineClassPath( result, loader );
    }

    return result;
}

public static List<URL> getURLs( ClassLoader cLoader ) {

    List<URL> result = new ArrayList<URL>();
    determineClassPath( result, cLoader );

    return result;
}

private static boolean DEBUG_CLASSPATH = true;

private static void determineClassPath( List<URL> result, ClassLoader cLoader ) {
    if( DEBUG_CLASSPATH ) {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( JavaUtils.class );
        log.debug( "ClassLoader {}", cLoader );
    }

    if( cLoader instanceof URLClassLoader ) {
        URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) cLoader;

        URL [] urls = cl.getURLs();
        if( urls == null ) { // On IBM/WebSphere this can be null
            urls = new URL[0];
        }

        if( DEBUG_CLASSPATH ) {
            Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( JavaUtils.class );
            log.debug( "    URLs: {}", urls );
        }
        result.addAll( Arrays.asList( urls ) );
    } else if( cLoader != null ) {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( JavaUtils.class );
        log.warn( "Unsupported class loader " + cLoader.getClass() );
    }
}
```

Things to look for:

- Was WebSphere able to unload your application when you re-deployed?
- How often is a class on the classpath? Make sure nothing exists twice.
- Make sure the JARs/EARs aren't corrupt